# passport is throwing user.authenticate is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I know this question has been asked before,but I couldn't found a proper answer.
Here is the console error.

```
TypeError: user.authenticate is not a function
at /home/sinnedde/WebstormProjects/web-services/config/strategies/local.js:24:23
```

Here is local.js used to check if the username and password are correct.

```
var passport = require('passport'),
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
User = require('mongoose').model('User');

module.exports = function () {
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({
        username: username
    }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
           return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'Invalid Username or Password'
            });
        }
        if (!user.authenticate(password)) {
            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'Invalid Username or Password'
            });
        }
        return done(null, user);
    });
 }));
};
```

Here is the signin method in the controller.

```
exports.signin = function (req, res, next) {
passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
   if (err || !user) {
       res.send(info);
   } else {
       res.json({
           status: 'true',
           message: 'Logged In'
       });
   }
 })(req, res, next);
};
```

I am sending a request through postman. If the username is not valid I am getting proper response, but if the password is not valid, it's throwing above error. I don't know what's wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Mongoose model does not have authenticate method, but you can add it to your schema.

Example code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var UserSchema = new Schema ({
  ...
});


UserSchema.methods.authenticate = function(password) {
  //implementation code goes here
}

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User');
```

Or you could use [Mongoose passport plugin](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose)

Comment: Thanks. But, I am using passport's local strategy to authenticate login. I have done it before, there was no problem. But now I am getting this. Is there any problem with the code ?

Comment: Maybe check out this link http://mherman.org/blog/2015/01/31/local-authentication-with-passport-and-express-4/#.WLxOrhIrJ60

Comment: I tried the Mongoose passport plugin. But it's throwing a new error `'cb' is not a function`

Comment: Have you defined Passport strategy like this: ```passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));``` ?

Comment: If you dont encrypt password, change ```!user.authenticate()``` to ```user.password !== password```

Comment: Well as you said, I am not encrypting for right now. So this works.Thank you so much for your help...

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error. In my case I forgot to add  `userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);` and don't forget to npm install 
 `passport-local-mongoose`package. I hope this will help you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As 'Hya' already said

Your Mongoose model does not have authenticate method, but you can add it to your schema.

Example code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var UserSchema = new Schema ({
  ...
});

// function should be like this to match encrypted password 
UserSchema.methods.authenticate = function(password) {      
  return this.password === this.hashPassword(password);
}
                ## OR ##

// if you are not using any encryption in password code then function should be like this 
UserSchema.methods.authenticate = function(password) {      
  return this.password === password;
}


mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User');
```